# Oracle SQL query optimizer (for speed/efficiency)

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle-database

I'm a data analyst (novice) who writes Oracle 18c SQL queries on a regular basis. I'm  aware that my SQL queries are sometimes not structured in the most efficient way possible.

I have a variety of options for learning how to write good queries (learn from books, post on SE Code Review, etc.).

With that said, I'd like to add a tool to my toolbelt: an Oracle SQL optimization tool.

- We're a Toad shop, so I use Toad base version for writing queries. As far as I can tell, Toad Base version doesn't include SQL optimization functionality.

---

What do you recommend as an Oracle SQL optimization tool? I'm willing to spend up to $300 CAD (out-of-pocket).

Comment: Welcome to our community!  Are you trying to optimize for speed or something else?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes, speed. Thanks. For instance, a query optimizer tool might warn me that the subselect, union, etc. in this query may not perform well (or is making too many full table scans): [Select workorders (via parameters) and their children](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252130/select-workorders-via-parameters-and-their-children).

Comment: You're welcome.  That would be a very useful and valuable tool.  Although I am not familiar with such a tool, hopefully someone else here will be.  I'm going to edit the title of your question to help improve its visibility and SEO.

Comment: Might also help to mention what database edition you're working with, and what licenses are available there. Thinking eg of Oracle EE with the Tuning Pack connected to an Enterprise Manager…